# Unable to compile Typescript using mocha and visual Studio Code Debugger

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

I'm trying to debug unit testing with Visual Studio Code and mocha, but when mocha launchs, throws this error.

> TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript: mfa/test/index.test.ts(4,20):
> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'assert' or its corresponding type
> declarations.

My launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "mocha tests",
      "type": "node",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "args": [ "-r", "ts-node/register", "${workspaceRoot}/test/**/*.test.ts", "--no-timeouts"],
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
      }
  ]
}
```

My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "ES2017", 
    "module": "commonJs",
    "allowJs": false, 
    "sourceMap": true, 

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,

    "esModuleInterop": true, 



  
    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mocha is unable to see the `tsconfig.json`. I've solved setting the `tsconfig.json` path in the `TS_NODE_PROJECT` environment variable. You need to add this snippet to your configuration:

```json
"env": {
    "TS_NODE_PROJECT": "${workspaceFolder}/tsconfig.json" // Or whatever path you have
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to install node types(assert typing is included there), to fix this run this command in project folder.

```
npm install --save @types/node
```